# Ionic v5 animation called twice on android

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using ionic **v5.6.13** and angular **v12.1.1**

I have an animation that fades in all elements with the `.fadeInBottom` class from the bottom.

It works fine on iOS, but on Android it sometimes calls the animation twice and i can't seem to see a pattern for when it's trigged twice.

### animations.service.ts

```
async fadeInBottom() {
    let elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('fadeInBottom'));
    const animations = elements.map((el, i) => {
        return this.animaitionCtrl.create()
            .addElement(el)
            .duration(150)
            .delay(i * 25)
            .fromTo('opacity', 0,1)
            .fromTo('transform', 'translateY(30px)', 'none')
            .play();
        });
    await Promise.all(animations)
    return true;
}
```

The animation is called in the page

```
async ionViewDidEnter() {
    await this.animationsService.fadeInBottom();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sometimes see a double animation on android when using 'opacity'.
I don't know it this will work out but try to set

```
 .fadeInBottom{
     opacity: 0; 
  }
```

to all the elements that you want to animate in you css file as a default initial value.

Apart from that, I'd rather making all the animations in my css file using @keyframe, you can read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: I have not tested what you suggested yet, but the reason i use the animation tool is because i also need to do some animation right before it leaves the page.